# "Well-being" versus "happiness"

Tags: word-choice, differences

What's the difference in meaning? When should I use each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well-being represents how well someone is faring as a person.  This could be with regards to someone's health, mental health, or the environment in which a person (usually a child) lives in.  It doesn't necessarily imply that such a person would be happy, simply that they live in a state that's "in their best interests."

Happiness on the contrary is that fleeting thing which people always desire but may or may not always be in their best well-being.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Can I say that all people in India and Indo-China feel happy but all people in the West pretend to be well?

Comment: Yes, though it doesn't make much sense "pretending to be well" isn't comparable with "feel happy."  I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: You may want to clear up "a state that's *good for them*," since it could mean "a state that they find good" or "a state that does them good." This may be the distinction you're trying to make in the answer as a whole (in which case it's probably even more important to be clear).

Comment: Good point.  Making corrections.

Answer (score 1):

*Well-being* is the state of being comfortable, healthy, or happy.
You can speak of well-being for an happy person, but a happy person can also not be healthy.

Answer (score 1):

I would summarize it succinctly as:

- 'Well-being' is a state of body.
- 'Happiness' is a state of mind.